# Query returning no results

Tags: php, mysql, select

This is the link the sends the $Row[pk_tId] to javascript:

```
    <a class=\"open-EditRow btn btn-primary btn-mini\" data-toggle=\"modal\" href=\"#myEditModal\" data-id=\"".$Row[pk_tId]."\" title=\"Edit this row\" \">Delete/Edit</a></td>";
```

This is the javascript that sends $Row[pk_tId] as groupId to the modal (on the same page):

```
   $(document).on("click", ".open-EditRow", function () {
     var myGroupId = $(this).data('id');
     $(".modal-body #groupId").val( myGroupId );
   });
```

This is the input field inside the modal that prints groupId:

```
   $id = "<input type=\"text\" name=\"groupId\" id=\"groupId\" value=\"\" />";
```

I echo out the $id:

```
   echo "Your id is: " . $id;
```

But when I try to select the $id to pull the record out of the database, it returns no records. The record is there.  Here is the statement:

```
   $q = "SELECT * FROM restable WHERE pk_tId == '" . $id . "'";
   if (mysql_num_rows($q) == 0){
        echo "No results";
    }
```

The only thing I get is "No results." I have a steady connection to the database. Why isn't this statement returning anything?  What am I missing? Please help.

Comment: Well, you're not running your query, for a start - you need to call `mysql_query()` to pass it to the database.

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing the actual query:

```
   $q = "SELECT * FROM restable WHERE pk_tId = '" . $id . "'";
   $query = mysql_query($q); // <- you forgot this line, $q is only a string
   if (mysql_num_rows($query ) === 0){
        echo "No results";
    }
```

The reason that the mysql_num_rows function still makes the condition, is because it returns false. 0 and false are the same if you compare with two equal signs. If you would have done this:

```
   if (mysql_num_rows($query ) === 0){ // This only fires when the functions return INT 0
   if (mysql_num_rows($query ) === false){ // This only fires when the function returns false (on error)
```

too clearify a bit more:

```
1==true   -> true
1===true  => false  (not the same type)
0==false  -> true
0===false -> false  (not the same type)
1=='1'    -> true
1==='1'   -> false (not the same type)
false=='false'  -> true
false==='false' -> false (not the same type)
```

Comment: I think I almost got it. Still testing. Using === 0 right now.

Comment: Can you tell me how I would display that in an <input value="">

Comment: I gave you the answer to your question. The question you are asking now are really basic. Try to find some 'php form handling' tutorials, because this is not explainable via answers and comments.

Answer (score 0):

You are not executing the query at any point:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM restable WHERE pk_tId == '" . $id . "'";
$query = mysql_query($sql); // <-----------missing from your code
if (mysql_num_rows($query) == 0){ // <------notice the difference
    echo "No results";
}
```

mysql_query is deprecated now btw (i've seen people's head get ripped off on this site for sill using it haha!)

I saw your other question from above ;-)

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM restable WHERE pk_tId == '" . $id . "'";
$q = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM restable WHERE pk_tId == '" . $id . "'"; // <--works with example below
$query = mysql_query($sql); // <-----------missing from your code
if (mysql_num_rows($query) == 0){ // <------notice the difference
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        echo '<input type="text" value="'.$row['COLUMN_NAME'].'">';
    }
}
```

Comment: What should I use then?

Comment: @JohnBeasley Check out PDO

Comment: TL;DR: check out mysqli_* because it should be a super simple transition........I personally took the time to learn and now prefer PDO but I've seen people suggest the mysqli_* extension. Seems pretty much the same as the regular mysql_* but something is more secure about it, idk (i skipped it and use PDO now because I connect to both Oracle and MySQL in my projects).

Comment: Thanks. I'm still testing, but I'm very close to making this work.